# How to extract the data from JSON.stringify?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application.

I want to display result in view. I have created array list in controller like this...

[image]

Now , I want to get the key text  and Value text from the array.

```
 $.each(result.StockData, function (key, Value) 
   {
    alert(key + "+" + JSON.stringify(Value));
   });
```

on alert, above code gives the  result like this...

```
0+{"Key":1,"Value":15}
```

I want to extract/Store the data of key and value in variables... 
how to do this ?

```
  $.each(result.StockData, function (key, Value) 
       {
      var_Key_Data = ? 
      var_Value_Data = ? 
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
$.each(result.StockData, function (index, item) {
    var Key_Data = item.Key; 
    //or var Key_Data = item["Key"];
    //or var Key_Data = result.StockData[index].Key;

    var Value_Data = item.Value; 
    //or var Key_Data = item["Value"];
    //or var Value_Data = result.StockData[index].Value;
});
```

If above code is not worked for your case then also try with the below code snippet.

```
$.each(result.StockData, function (index, item1) {

    var item = eval(item1);

    var Key_Data = item.Key; 
    //or var Key_Data = item["Key"];
    //or var Key_Data = result.StockData[index].Key;

    var Value_Data = item.Value; 
    //or var Key_Data = item["Value"];
    //or var Value_Data = result.StockData[index].Value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
$.each($.parseJSON(result.StockData), function(key, value) {
        alert(key + ' is ' + value);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `$.each` function, key is an index value, while value parameter contains all the json data which you get from ajax method